# LostFocus not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, lostfocus

Got a bit stuck and could use some help.
To achieve: whenever click outside of the StackPanel - it Visibilty should change to Hidden.

Pretty easy one, I wrote the next condition:

```
private void pnlLeftMenu_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (pnlLeftMenu.IsFocused == false)
        {
            pnlLeftMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
    }
```

Where pnlLeftMenu is the panel, which should be triggered.
Here is the xaml piece, with described properties:

```
    <StackPanel x:Name="pnlLeftMenu"                    
                Orientation="Vertical" 
                Height="475" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                Margin="57,0,0,0"
                Visibility="Hidden"
                Background="{StaticResource BlueFadedBrush}" 
                IsVisibleChanged="pnlLeftMenu_IsVisibleChanged" 
                Focusable="True"
                LostFocus="pnlLeftMenu_LostFocus" >
```

No worries about the fact, that it is already hidden - it is a side menu, which become vissible on button click. That part works fine.

So the question is: what am I missing? Cause when it looks like this - the click outside of the panel does't give any reaction.

Comment: initially it is hidden then how it got focus?

Comment: Gains property change on click:         private void btnLeftMenuShow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            pnlLeftMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;            
        }

Comment: As well, I just tried to force focus: private void btnLeftMenuShow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {            
            pnlLeftMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;           
            pnlLeftMenu.Focus();
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you add a click event to the parent container of stack panel and inside the click event handler try like

```
   if (pnlLeftMenu.IsVisible)
    {
        pnlLeftMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
```